# How to get the battery status from an Android phone with Python connected to a PC via Bluetooth?

Tags: battery, bluetooth, android-pc

Is there a way to interrogate an Android phone with Python on a PC and/or Linux to get battery status while connected via Bluetooth?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible via Bluetooth, but with ADB over Wifi you could call `dumpsys batteryproperties` respectively `dumpsys battery` for Android before Oreo/8.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find ADB documentation, so I can figure out how to connect to an android phone and issue the calls you mentioned?

Comment: Use your favorite search engine and search for `adb wifi android`.